# Entity Client not installed but entity working fine

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am getting the following error when I debug my setupConnections method

```
    public string SetupConnections(SourceDatabases database)
    {
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder efBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

        try
        { 

        string metaData = @"res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl";
        string initialcatalog = "";
        const string appName = "EntityFramework";
        const string providerName = "System.Data.EntityClient";
        if (database == SourceDatabases.COASTALCAROLINAPODIATRY)
        {
            initialcatalog = "COASTALCAROLINAPODIATRY";
        }
        if (database == SourceDatabases.COASTALVISIONCARE)
        {
            initialcatalog = "COASTALVISIONCARE";
        }
        if (database == SourceDatabases.ELEANORSAHN)
        {
            initialcatalog = "ELEANORSAHN";
        }

        if (database == SourceDatabases.GLAUCOMACONSULTANTS)
        {
            initialcatalog = "COASTALCAROLINAPODIATRY";
        }

        if (database == SourceDatabases.MARIANNEROSEN)
        {
            initialcatalog = "COASTALCAROLINAPODIATRY";
        }
        const string dataSource = "sourcenet";
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlBuilder.DataSource = dataSource;
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = initialcatalog;
        sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
        sqlBuilder.UserID = "scheduler";
        sqlBuilder.Password = "BORG8472";
        sqlBuilder.ApplicationName = appName;


        efBuilder.Metadata = metaData;
        efBuilder.Provider = providerName;
        efBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ConnectionString;
        }
        catch(Exception EX)
        {

        }
        return efBuilder.ConnectionString;
    }
```

It claims the following that is not installed but I have had no issues using ef through out my project is this another nuget i need

> The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.EntityClient' is
>   either not registered in the machine or application config file, or
>   could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.
>
> **Inner**: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not
>   be installed.

My Providers Simply have the following in my app.config

```
 <providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

You can see from below I have it installed this is bugging the hell out of me it only complains when i switch connections using the below method?.
[image]

Comment: What is in the inner exception? Also, try deleting the bin folder and doing a rebuild.

Comment: @CodingYoshi please see my edit above

Comment: @CodingYoshi deleting bin and object didnt solve the issue im really at a loss as to what is wrong

Comment: @CodingYoshi I have no issues without using the above to define my connections it works fine but when i switch on the fly it fails with that error !

Comment: It is not `System.Data.EntityClient`, it is `System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto but when i do that it says property meta data is not support I need to be able to pass the meta data of my conneciton string !

Comment: @David Then that's the real issue. There is no `System.Data.EntityClient` in the .NET Framework, so this question should either be deleted or edited completely

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto but how does one pass meta data using the above i seen this done somewhere

Comment: Why not just build the entire connection string as a `string` and pass it to the constructor of your `DbContext`? The helper classes are not needed at all

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it ended up in my context I was doing database.connectionstring which of course as all no doesnt support meta data manged to solve the problem ish